# React/Redux Loading application state in component constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm rendering high-order component, say `Application` and I need to fetch some data from server, before it's rendered. What I do, in constructor of `Application` I issue `loadApplicationState()` action, that performs server call and prepares initial state.

Some simplified code,

```
class Application extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { dispatch } = this.props;

    dispatch(loadApplicationState());
  }

  render() {
    const { stateLoaded } = this.props.state;

    render (
      <div>
        { stateLoaded ? renderApp() : renderProgress() }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function loadApplicationState() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    // fetch data and once ready,
    applicationStateLoaded(data);
  }
}
```

I've tried that on practice, it works fine. But not sure is this a right approach? Especially using a constructor for such purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We run this in `componentDidMount`, and then test for an `$isLoading` flag in our Redux state, rendering either a loading indicator or the actual UI. Something like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  $isLoading: state.initialState.$isLoading
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  loadApplicationState(){ dispatch(loadApplicationState()); }
})

export class Application extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.loadApplicationState();
  }

  render(){
    const {
      $isLoading
    } = this.props;

    {$isLoading ? (<Loader />) : <ActualApplication />}
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Application)
```

Comment: Isn't that `componentDidMount` and `constructor` the same for ES6 react applications?

Comment: `constructor ` is a substitution for `componentWillMount`, not `componentDidMount`.

Comment: but seems to me that constructor is a good place to issue `loadState` action.. why it should be done in `componentDidMount` only?

Comment: `constructor` is not a substitute for either `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`. `constructor`'s invocation is completely up to the whims of React, and it could be invoked even if the component will never be mounted. On the other hand, `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` have well defined semantics. Besides, it's good general programming practice to not put side effects (like server calls!) in constructors.